# pyspark run linear regression with dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, linear-regression

I tried to run linear regression with dataframe in pyspark, but after I tried functions to make fields, labels, it still gives me an error. Can someone help me to figure out how to run linear regression with dataframe?

```
import pyspark.mllib
import pyspark.mllib.regression
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
#from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
```

my data looks like,

```
df_all_shorted.head(2)

[Row(bonica_rid=u'cand1457', party=100, vote_date=u'2001-01-03', vote_choice=6, vs_idealPoint=-0.514169271337908, vs_cuttingpoint=-0.514169271337908, vs_rcdir=1, fecyear_new=u'1992', Cand_ID_new=u'H2MA11060', state_new=u'MA', recipient_cfscore_new=-0.758, num_givers_total_new=1533, cand_gender_new=u'M', total_receipts_new=169089.0, total_indiv_contrib_new=105870.0, total_pac_contribs_new=0.0, ran_primary_new=1, ran_general_new=1, district_partisanship_new=-0.119),
 Row(bonica_rid=u'cand1457', party=100, vote_date=u'2001-01-03', vote_choice=6, vs_idealPoint=-0.514169271337908, vs_cuttingpoint=-0.514169271337908, vs_rcdir=1, fecyear_new=u'1992', Cand_ID_new=u'H2MA11060', state_new=u'MA', recipient_cfscore_new=-0.758, num_givers_total_new=1533, cand_gender_new=u'M', total_receipts_new=0.0, total_indiv_contrib_new=0.0, total_pac_contribs_new=0.0, ran_primary_new=0, ran_general_new=0, district_partisanship_new=-0.119)]
```

and

```
training = df_all_shorted.rdd.map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(line[0],[line[1:]])
```

I tried this code and get an error,

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

so I changed to

```
training = df_all_shorted.rdd.map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(line[0],[line[1:]]))

and it worked, but when I run 

lr = LinearRegression()\
.setMaxIter(10)\
.setRegParam(0.3)\
.setElasticNetParam(0.8)
lrModel = lr.fit(training)
```

Error occured,

```
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the `LinearRegression` function you are trying to use is from `pyspark.ml` not from `pyspark.mllib`. Your global variable space still recognizes `LinearRegression` is from `pyspark.ml` module after you commented out the line `from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression`. Restart and run it again.